# send ajax data to mysql with php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

i implement the below javascript function to collect the data and display them, but i need to save these data into mysql database for tracking data, i tried the below php code to connect into mysql locally but didn't work, i think the issue i don't know how to collect data and insert them in a query

here's the javascript code:

```
function Script2()
{
  var player = GetPlayer();    
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });   
 $.ajax({
url: "data.php",
           type: "GET",
           processData: true,
           data: {"entry.939953095" :player.GetVar("username"),
"entry.391274481" :player.GetVar("Slide1"),
"entry.822772676" :player.GetVar("slide2"), 
"entry.934389578" :player.GetVar("slide3"),
"entry.1669272782" :player.GetVar("slide4"),
"entry.1486049396" :player.GetVar("Slide5"), 
"entry.264581670" :player.GetVar("slide6"),

          dataType: "jsonp",
           success: function (data) {
               processData(data);
           }
});
```

the php file to connect to database and store the data

```
<?php

if(isset($_REQUEST))
{
$connect_error='sorry we\'re experincing connection error';
@mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die($connect_error);
mysql_select_db('lo-test') or die($connect_error);

error_reporting(E_ALL && ~E_NOTICE);

$data=$_GET['player.GetVar("Slide1")'];
$sql="INSERT INTO lo-test(text2) VALUES ('$data')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

}
?>
```

any advice for my code and how to use Get or Post to handle the variables

Comment: `$_GET['player.GetVar("Slide1")']` - should be - `$_GET['entry.391274481']`

Comment: As a side note, you should switch to [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) or [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) and use prepared statements. Your current code is open to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

You will get your data like this

```
$data = $_GET['entry.939953095'];
```

Or you can also trying dumping `$_GET` variable and have a look on all the keys it has